# CSS for multiple overlapping images with box shadow

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to get 3 images to overlap and look exactly like in the image below. I cant seem to replicate the style with box shadow, my images just appear in a line.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="image">
                <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/"/></a>
                <div class="overlay"><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/?random"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/"/></a>
                <div class="overlay"><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/?random"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/"/></a>
                <div class="overlay"><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/?random"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container {
            max-width: 940px;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .image {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            margin: 1%;
            width: 31.3%;
        }
         .image img { 
            height: auto;
            width: 100%; 
        }
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        .overlay:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .overlay img{
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with your `margin` values. `auto` on either or both sides (and you can add a percentage on the opposite side to avoid "perfect" positions), and negative `margin-top` for `.image + .image` to pull them upwards and overlap.

```css
.container {
            max-width: 940px;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .image {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            width: 62.6%;
        }
        .image:nth-child(1) {
          margin-right: auto;
          z-index: 3;
        }
        .image:nth-child(2) {
          margin-left: auto;
          z-index: 2;
        }
        .image:nth-child(3) {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          z-index: 1;
        }
        .image + .image {
          margin-top: -15.65%;
        }
        .image img { 
            height: auto;
            width: 100%; 
        }
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        .overlay:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .overlay img{
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="image">
                <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/"/></a>
                <div class="overlay"><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/?random"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/"/></a>
                <div class="overlay"><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/?random"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/"/></a>
                <div class="overlay"><img src="https://picsum.photos/280/280/?random"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I changed the `width` value to make this work with your example.

You'll notice I've used `:nth-child` to target each box individually, you could of course use something else. Also note the use of `z-index` to make sure each box is above the following one. If you want boxes to be layered above the previous one, you can remove the `z-index` as the document order will be the default order.

I'll let you handle the styling of the boxes, this should get you where you need.